# Firebase notification gives me "Success" but I don't get the notification on IOS

Tags: php, firebase, codeigniter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get notifications on Android but when I send the notification to an IOS device, it doesn't get received, even though it says success.

I added badges, sound, vibration, priority.. etc but none of this solved the problem.

```
function sendNotification($title, $body, $aid,$destination)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $message = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'body' => strip_tags($body),
        'vibrate' => 1,
        'sound' => 1,
        "action" => "url",
        'sound' => 'default', 
        'badge' => '1',
        'priority'=>'high',
        "action_destination" => $destination,
    );

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $aid,
        'data' => $message
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=KEYHERE',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

The mobile developer says that theres a new firebase update and I frankly think hes bsing... Can someone explain to me whats going on? I think my part here is done, but you guys might see something wrong with my code...